# RestKit - POST array of objects with attachments

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit-0.20

I am creating a task application which has offline mode.

While in offline mode, I am setting `isSync` attribute to false for each object, so that when network is available I could fetch these unsynced objects with predicate and POST them to server.

The problem is I am not being able to add attachments with each object.

In online I am sending `POST` request with attachment for single object like this:

```
if (attachments != nil && attachments.count > 0) {
    task.total_attachments = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:attachments.count];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:task
                                                                                           method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                             path:URL_TASKS
                                                                                       parameters:nil
                                                                        constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

                                                                            int counter = 0;
                                                                            for (NSDictionary *dic in attachments) {
                                                                                [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([dic objectForKey:@"image"], 0.7)
                                                                                                            name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"attachment[%i]", counter]
                                                                                                        fileName:[dic objectForKey:@"name"]
                                                                                                        mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
                                                                                counter++;
                                                                            }
                                                                        }];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                               managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]
                                                                                                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                                                                                KLog(@"success");

                                                                                                                completionHandler((DBTasks *)[mappingResult firstObject], nil);

                                                                                                            } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                                                                KLog(@"fail");
                                                                                                                completionHandler(nil, error);
                                                                                                            }];
    [operation start];

}
```

It seems attachments are added per request, not per object. Now when I am POSTing an array of objects instead of single object, how can I add attachments with each object? So that server could decide which attachment is added for which object.

Comment: If you want help, fix your code formatting so people can read your code.

Comment: Add the object identity into the name?

Comment: @Wain, thanks for reply, but I didn't get your hint. Could you please explain?

Comment: You set the name to `attachment[%i]`, but you can add more info to that tag...

Comment: Thanks @Wain, I finally appended a uniqueId of task in `formData`, and now web developer can get the correct attachment for task.

`[formData appendPartWithFormData:[task.unique_id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"uniqueId"];`

Comment: Please add your own answer to the question and accept it :)

Comment: I think you should add your comment as answer, and I should accept it. :)